# Is it possible to view and use older versions of a file by only accessing my local repository?

Tags: git, github

Lets say, I don't have access to github. How is my local repository useful to me? Can I roll back files to early versions? If so, how is it done?

Comment: Your local repo should be a full git repo. Did you read the http://book.git-scm.com/?

Comment: This is basically the *entire point* of a distributed VCS. It sounds like you need to back up and understand the general idea of your version control, not ask specific questions. [The Git Parable](http://tom.preston-werner.com/2009/05/19/the-git-parable.html) is a nice nontechnical introduction to the core way Git works. Also popular are the community book (Mat's link) and [Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local repository contains a full history. This is easily seen by launching `gitk`, a graphical explorer of your git history.

To get older versions of files, you can use for example `git checkout <revision> <file>`. For example `git checkout HEAD^ foo.txt` will give you the `foo.txt` from the previous revision.

Another way of exploring old versions of files is `git show <revision>:<path>` which will show you the old contents of the file in a pager instead of checking it out into your working tree.

The only commands that access other repositories (github in this case) are `git push`, `git pull` and `git fetch`. All other git operations work solely on locally available information.

Comment: Well, there are some other commands which perform network operations (`git remote` comes to mind), but apart from that +1

Answer (score 0):

Your local repository has the entire project history for whatever branches it contains.  Please note it might not contain all branches listed on github.

You should read the [git-checkout man page](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-checkout.html), which explains how one accesses various versions, and the [git-show man page](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-show.html), which differs slightly in syntax.  You should probably also read the [reset section](http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html) in the Git Book as well .

In short, `git checkout <revision> <file>` replaces the current working with the one form `<revision>` and `git show <revision>:<file>` just shows it.  `HEAD` names the last committed revision, `HEAD^` the preceding one.  `git log` lists them all, most recent first with commit messages.

Check out [git-bisect](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-bisect.html) if you want to see something really cool.  :)